# How to Parse Json webService response in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, datacontractserializer

I want to display data in Listbox without using any DLL.And my webservice responding in json format.

My Web service Response is as below.it has more than 800 records

```
[
    {
    "st_id":"1",
        "st_name":"name xyz"
    },
{

  "st_id":"2",
   "st_name":"name ABC"
},
{

  "st_id":"3",
   "st_name":"name HIJK"
},
{
  "st_id":"4",
   "st_name":"name OPQ"
},
]
```

my Class for the data is as below

```
[DataContract]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember=("st_id")]
    public bool st_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember=("st_name")]
    public string st_name { get; set; }

}
```

i m trying serialize object using DataContractJsonSerializer & m getting WS response in Stream.But i am not able to serialize.Suggest links or basic tutorial for Serilize and Deserilize of the json

```
DataContractJsonSerializer stdserialize = 
    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Student));
Student stuser = (Student)stdserialize.ReadObject(responseStream);
```

so please help for the json response parsing & suggest link for datacontract and all which gives knowledge from basics.
Thanks,

Comment: Why have you specified "without using any DLL"? I would use Json.NET, which works fine in WP7...

Comment: but its not diplaying while m trying adding reference for the Json.Net. & i also tried for the namespace using System.Json;

Comment: Well Json.NET doesn't use that namespace... and you've got to download it from json.codeplex.com first...

Comment: ok thnks jon actually i was jst trying to use tht namespace as i read from ths URL. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). bt how can i read response with the above code.

Comment: Read the documentation on http://json.codeplex.com. It's pretty good. (Heck, it's entirely possible that DataContractJsonSerializer should work for you - you haven't said what happens when you've tried it.)

Comment: Okay, so you need to do the same sort of debugging you normally would - use a temporary variable of type `object` for the return value from `ReadObject`, moving the cast to a separate statement. Then put a breakpoint on that line, and see what the type *actually* is.

Comment: ok thankx...the exception is System.InvalidCastException was unhandled Message=InvalidCastException...now i'll try to implement with the json.codeplex...

Answer (score 0):

You declared st_id as a `bool`, but the type of data you're trying to deserialize is string (which can be converted to numbers - not to booleans). Try declaring it as `string` and it should work.

Also, the response is an *array* of objects, so the type you should use is `Student[]`:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer stdserialize = 
    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Student[]));
Student stuser = (Student[])stdserialize.ReadObject(responseStream);
```